# Run jobs in parallel

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, xargs

I would like to run a large number of intensive processes in parallel, where I loop over different parameters with for loops. A number of answers to similar questions mention that running processes in parallel can be done with xargs, but none of them seem to mention if or how this can be done if the parameters change for each command.

As an example (pseudo code):

```
for paramA in 1 2 3
  for paramB in 1 2 3
    ./intensiveCommand $paramA $paramB
  end
end
```

I would like to parallellize intensiveCommand

Or is there an easier way then using xargs?

Comment: you can add & sign in the end of command with "intensiveCommand". This will run jobs in parralel.

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't take into account the load, right? So it will keep adding processes, due to which it will start swapping and slow down the processes.

Comment: In this case you can parse load average from the output of uname and run new processes conditionally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [GNU parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html). It has a `--load` option avoid overloading the computer.

```
parallel --load 100% ./intensiveCommand ::: 1 2 3 ::: 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
number_of_cores=4   #<-- number of processorcores, in my case: 4

for paramA in 1 2 3
do
    for paramB in 1 2 3
    do
        #========== automatic load regulator ==================
        sleep 1
        while [  $( pgrep -c "intensiveCommand" ) -ge "$number_of_cores" ]
        do
            kill -SIGSTOP $$
        done
        #======================================vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv            

        ( ./intensiveCommand $paramA $paramB ; kill -SIGCONT $$ ) &

    done
done
```

This program will put itself on **hold** if there are running as much intensiveCommands as there are cores. A finished intensiveCommand will let the program **continue** (see the **kill -SIGCONT $$** ).
The program checks again and will launch intensiveCommands until it locks again when the max number of intensiveCommands is reached again.

The sleep is to overcome the latency between the launch of an intensiveCommand and it's appearance in the process table.

Comment: Any explanation on how this works? `pgrep -c "intensiveCommand"` counts the number of instances of "intensiveCommand" in the currently running process list... `-ge` means "greater than or equal to"... The line `( ... ) &` starts some kind of new process in the background? Other than that I've not got a clue how it works

Answer (score 1):

Very tight scheduling in "1 slot per core",rock solid and simple.

```
#/bin/bash

#use the filedescriptor as a kind of queue to fill the processing slots.

exec 3< <(

    for PARAM_A in 1 2 3
    do
        for PARAM_B in 1 2 3
        do
             echo $PARAM_A $PARAM_B
        done
    done
)

#4 seperate processing slots running parallel 
while read -u 3 PARA PARB; do "intensiveCommand $PARA $PARB" ; done &
while read -u 3 PARA PARB; do "intensiveCommand $PARA $PARB" ; done &
while read -u 3 PARA PARB; do "intensiveCommand $PARA $PARB" ; done &
while read -u 3 PARA PARB; do "intensiveCommand $PARA $PARB" ; done &

#only exit when 100% sure that all processes ended
while pgrep "intensiveCommand" &>"/dev/null" ; do wait ; done
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this which works pretty nicely - read the comments at the top to see how it works.

```
#!/bin/bash
################################################################################
# File: core
# Author: Mark Setchell
# 
# Primitive, but effective tool for managing parallel execution of jobs in the
# shell. Based on, and requiring REDIS.
#
# Usage:
#
# core -i 8 # Initialise to 8 cores, or specify 0 to use all available cores
# for i in {0..63}
# do
#   # Wait for a core, do a process, release core
#   (core -p; process; core -v)&
# done
# wait
################################################################################
function usage {
    echo "Usage: core -i ncores # Initialise with ncores. Use 0 for all cores."
    echo "       core -p        # Wait (forever) for free core."
    echo "       core -v        # Release core."
    exit 1
}

function init {
    # Delete list of cores in REDIS
    echo DEL cores | redis-cli > /dev/null 2>&1
    for i in `seq 1 $NCORES`
    do
       # Add another core to list of cores in REDIS
       echo LPUSH cores 1 | redis-cli > /dev/null 2>&1
    done
    exit 0
}

function WaitForCore {
    # Wait forever for a core to be available
    echo BLPOP cores 0 | redis-cli > /dev/null 2>&1
    exit 0
}

function ReleaseCore {
    # Release or give back a core
    echo LPUSH cores 1 | redis-cli > /dev/null 2>&1
    exit 0
}

################################################################################
# Main
################################################################################
while getopts "i:pv" optname
  do
    case "$optname" in
      "i")
        if [ $OPTARG -lt 1 ]; then
           NCORES=`sysctl -n hw.logicalcpu`;    # May differ if not on OSX, maybe "nproc" on Linux
        else
           NCORES=$OPTARG
        fi
    init $NCORES
        ;;
      "p")
    WaitForCore
        ;;
      "v")
    ReleaseCore
        ;;
      "?")
        echo "Unknown option $OPTARG"
        ;;
    esac
done
usage
```

By way of example, the following takes 10 seconds (not 80) to do 16 waits of 5 seconds each:

```
core -i 8 
for i in {0..15}
do
   # Wait for a core, do a process, release core
   (core -p ; sleep 5 ; core -v)&
done
wait
```

Comment: Yes, it is really easy to install and run. The key function in it "BLPOP" which does a blocking wait for an item in a list. This allows me to control exactly how many processes can run at once. If I want 8, I put 8 items in the list at the start and take one each time I do a job then I give it back to the list when finished.